# Implementing async- await() in kotlin coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I have created function as below :

```
fun getPercentage(id:String): String {
    var percentage=""
    scope.launch {
        percentage=repo.getPercentage(id)?.get(0)?.percent.toString()
        Log.e("$$$ value >>","$$$ value >>"+percentage)
    }
    Log.e("$$$ value outside >>","$$$ value >>"+percentage)
    return percenatge
}
```

Here, I can not return the updated value using the varibale : percentage.

Logs I am getting is as below :

```
$$$ value outside >> 
$$$ value >> 50
```

means I can't return the latest value. something going wrong with the flow.

Someone suggested me to use async{} and await(). But I don't know How it will be helpful here?

Please guide. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `getPercentage` function creates a coroutine in the background via the [launch](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/launch.html) function, and then continues without waiting. Your "outside" code is therefore running before the "inner" coroutine completes.

The first option is to use the [async](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/async.html) function instead to return a [Deferred](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-deferred/index.html) value from the coroutine:

```kotlin
fun getPercentage(id:String): Deferred<String> {
    return scope.async {
        percentage=repo.getPercentage(id)?.get(0)?.percent.toString()
        Log.e("$$$ value >>","$$$ value >>"+percentage)
    }
}
```

Note of course that its more likely you want to make `getPercentage` a suspend function, and then call `await` directly:

```kotlin
suspend fun getPercentage(id:String): String {
    val percentageDeferred = scope.async {
        percentage=repo.getPercentage(id)?.get(0)?.percent.toString()
        Log.e("$$$ value >>","$$$ value >>"+percentage)
    }
    val percentage = percentageDeferred.await()
    Log.e("$$$ value outside >>","$$$ value >>"+percentage)
    return percentage    
}
```

It's also likely you want to do something else before the `await` otherwise you're probably just better off making `repo.getPercentage` a suspend function as well, and calling it directly:

```kotlin
suspend fun getPercentage(id:String): String {
    // if repo.getPercentage is a suspend function, this call suspends
    // like the await in the previous example
    val percentage = repo.getPercentage(id)?.get(0)?.percent.toString()
    Log.e("$$$ value outside >>","$$$ value >>"+percentage)
    return percentage    
}
```

See [Concurrent using async](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/composing-suspending-functions.html#concurrent-using-async) in the Kotlin docs.

Comment: giving me : suspend function await() should only call from the coroutine scope. how can I return the value in that case sir ?

Comment: @JaiminModi I've updated the answer for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you necessarily need to use async in this case, particularly. You only need to be aware that whatever is inside `launch { ... }` is executed asynchronously. So by the time `getPercentage` returns, your coroutine may not have even started yet.

Keeping that in mind, I believe you may want to change the way your code works. The only way you can make `fun getPercentage(id: String): String` work without changing that signature is by replacing `scope.launch { ... }` with `scope.runBlocking { ... }`, but you probably don't want to do that, because it would block your thread.

Instead, you might change `getPercentage` to be a `suspend` method:

```
suspend fun getPercentage(id: String): String {
    return repo.getPercentage(id)?.get(0)?.percent.toString()
}
```

However, `suspend` methods can only be called from inside a coroutine. So you would need to call it like this:

```
scope.launch {
    val percentage = getPercentage("some ID")
    // Now you can use `percentage` for whatever you need.
}
```